# Tensorflow Serving loading multiple models from S3

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-s3, tensorflow-serving

We have successfully integrated our container to load models from an s3 bucket. However, we are unable to figure out how to load multiple models. Ideally, we would like to start our container pointing to a bucket that has no models. Over time we would like copy models to s3 which would be served by tensorflow-serving.

```
docker run \
  -p 8501:8501 \
  -e S3_USE_HTTPS=0 \
  -e S3_VERIFY_SSL=0 \
  -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<key> \
  -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<access_key> \
  -e MODEL_BASE_PATH=s3://test-bucket/tf_model_directory/ \
  -e MODEL_NAME=SAR \
  -e AWS_LOG_LEVEL=3 \
  -t tensorflow/serving
```

The above command expects a model name to be specified. I was wondering if there is a way to start it without the model name or force tensorflow-serving to pick the config from the s3 path.

Comment: Did you try using a model config file? https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config#model_server_config_details

Comment: I read about the config file. I am not sure how to pass the path to the docker container.

Comment: I think you can specify the path to the model (`s3://.../tf_model_dir/`) in the model.conf file, upload the model.conf file to the same bucket and pass its location to the `--model_config_file` flag: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config

Comment: I did try to do that but it doesn't seem to be working. When I don't specify the model name it defaults to the "model" folder and ends up failing because the model folder doesn't exist. I think the behaviour is coming from the following code : https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile#L49.  It seems I have to either build a new docker file or modify the entry point to make this work.

Comment: @AKG Did you find a solution? How does your model.config and S3 structure looks? I can't get this to work with S3.

Comment: Yes. I did manage to find the solution. We have it deployed in production and seems to be working fine.

Comment: Can you share your solution @AKG?